# Why won't this semi circle grow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Basically, 
I have two semi-circles. One(circle0) is of constant radius and the inner semi-circle(circle1, with gradient) is of variable radius. circle1 has initial value of 1% radius of circle0.

I want to input a value in the target box(0-100) for the new radius of circle1. I have put an interval of 100ms for a 1% step in radius of circle1 to show it growing but it doesn't seem to work. 
I am not very good at javascript/jquery but any help is greatly appreciated.

See demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/nilerafter24/ma845o6d/3/

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function circle_set(delta) {
        if (!delta) {
            return false;
        } else {
            var e = document.querySelectorAll('circle[id^=circle]');
            var radius0 = parseInt(e[0].getAttribute('r'), 10);
            var radius1 = parseInt(e[1].getAttribute('r'), 10);
            var currentRadius = (delta / 100) * 50;

            if (currentRadius <= radius0) {

                setTimeout(function() {
                    if (radius1 <= currentRadius) {
                        radius1++;
                        e[1].setAttribute('r', String(radius0) + "%");
                    },
                }, 100);
            }
        }
    }

    var inputTargetButton = document.getElementById('executeTarget');
    var inputTargetValue = document.getElementById('setTarget');

    if (inputTargetButton.type == 'button') {
        inputTargetButton.onclick = function() {
            circle_set(inputTargetValue.value)
        }
    }
});
```

**Edit:**
Corrected big mistake.Changed radius0 to radius1. Need more coffee.

Comment: you're missing a `}` before  `, 100);` in your timeout

Comment: Also if (radius0 <= currentRadius) condition fails ....I confused with ur condition. first If true, then second if should be failed, reciprocal. what is currentRadius .

Comment: @nisar currentRadius is what the user inputs in the Targetbox. 
radius0 is always smaller than currentRadius because it is the inital radius. There is no fail condition. that code just doesn't run if it fails to meet the condition.

Comment: @AminGharavi corrected.but still doesn't run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use setInterval for your function, also your condition is incorrect. work this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ea2fq1ka/)

```
setInterval(function() {
    if (radius1 <= currentRadius) {
        radius1++;
        e[1].setAttribute('r', String(radius1) + "%");
    }
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, what you have is increasing the radius of the larger semicircle, `radius0`. You want to increase `radius1` and apply that to `circle1`.

Second thing is that `setTimeout()` will only call the function once. You need to use `setInterval()` to call the function every 100ms. But, since you don't want it to continue calling after the radius has reached `currentRadius`, you should clear it at that point using `clearInterval()`:

```
if (currentRadius <= radius0) {
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        if (radius1 <= currentRadius) {
            radius1++;                   
            e[1].setAttribute('r', String(radius1) + "%");
        }
        else {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

Check out this working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q4ns6q0m/1/

Comment: This answer is also correct. I chose Nisar's only because it came first. Thanks though. This problem had me scratching for hours. I have used setTimeout before to call a function in intervals but I think in that instance I had another timed function make the callback so I got confused.

Comment: You know what they say, first is better than better.

Answer (score 1):

From what I tested, in this code:

```
if (radius0 <= currentRadius) {
   radius0++;
   e[1].setAttribute('r', String(radius0) + "%");
  }, 
}
```

the if condition is never satisfied.